# C# - Need help connecting to IPEndPoint

Tags: c#, sip, system.net

Ok, I am trying to use the System.Net.Sockets part of the .Net Framework 4 to connect to an IPEndPoint.

First I declare the IP address as a variable like so

```
IPAddress myIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.15.200");
```

Then I declare my IP endpoint as a variable like so:

```
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(myIpAddress, 5001);
```

Then I try and bind to this socket, like so:

```
socket.Bind(ip);
```

The response I get is as follows:

> The requested address is not valid in its context.

However this is not the case. The IP address exists and is currently active. The IP address in question is a VOIP phone on a SIP trunk.

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: how are you creating the object System.Net.Sockets.Socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bind` is used to associate to a *local* address and port and is where the packets will be marked as coming *from*. You need to use `Connect` instead.